# Use of Mysql4 and Resource in different modules in same project

Tags: magento-1.9, module, resource-model

There are some modules where Mysql4 is used and now I have created some new module with Resource for `ModuleResource` in `config.xml`.

Does it has any effect of performance of site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to have any impact on the performance of your site. The naming convention wants you to use `Resource`, as even though there is backwards compatibility with `Mysql4`, it's been deprecated since Magento 1.6